# vb/asp.net radgrid from sql server storedprocedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, radgrid

I'm using Teleriks radgrid and am able to properly populate it but am not able to add things to the grid like Paging and Sorting. I'm assuming once that click event happens it's not seeing the data any more. Any ideas on a work around?

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridReportHistory" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" Width="1350px">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

On page load:

```
Protected Sub ReportHistory()

        Dim Da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim Ds As New System.Data.DataSet
        'Dim sUser = "crmc1"
        sUser = Mid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, InStr(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "\", CompareMethod.Text) + 1)
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("ReportsRunHistory", GetUDBSQLConn2)
        cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Logins", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmd.Parameters("@Logins").Value = sUser
        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Da.Fill(Ds)

        With RadGridReportHistory
            .DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)  
            .DataBind()
        End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't used RadGrid, but in general you have to rebind grid on every postback. You have the call to ReportHistory in Page_Load, but I assume it only does that on initial load, not on the postback? Add call to ReportHistory to Sorted and PageIndexChanged event (I assume something like this exists in the grid)

Comment: @Yuriy That makes sense and there are postback events I can try. I think my issue might be if they click next page, how to actually grab "the next set of items" instead of the ones that are already being displayed(if that makes sense)